# Finding $S_{ADE}:S_{DBCE}$ given that $\angle A = 30^\circ$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, area, plane-geometry

Suppose $\triangle ABC$ is acute, and $\angle A = 30^\circ.$ Then, draw a circle with $BC$ as the diameter. Let the intersection points of the circle drawn and $AB$ and $AC$ be $D$ and $E,$ respectively. Find $S_{ADE}:S_{DBCE}.$

---

I first made a diagram, and I drew out the points. However, I wasn't quite sure where to go from here, although I was thinking of trying to use the fact that $\angle A = 30^\circ.$ Can I have a hint please?

Comment: What is $S_{ADE}$? Is it the perimeter of triangle $ADE$?

Comment: It is the area of triangle $ADE.$ Likewise, $S_{DBCE}$ is the area of quadrilateral $DBCE.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\measuredangle ADE=\measuredangle ACB, $ we see that $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta AED.$

Also, $\measuredangle BED=90^{\circ}.$

Thus, $$\frac{S_{\Delta ADE}}{S_{BDEC}}=\frac{S_{\Delta ADE}}{S_{\Delta ABC}-S_{\Delta ADE}}=\frac{1}{\frac{S_{\Delta ABC}}{S_{\Delta ADE}}-1}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{AB}{AE}\right)^2-1}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\right)^2-1}=3$$

Comment: $\frac{AB}{AE}$ is actually equal to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. This means that $\frac{S_{\Delta ADE}}{S_{BDEC}}=3$.

Comment: @Tc14 Hd  Thank you! It was my delirium. I fixed.